# Multiple report server instances - SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have SQL Server Standard edition on a machine. There are two instances - prod and test (\Test).

Currently SSRS 2014 is running on there. I would like to install SSRS 2017 and point it to the `\Test` instance.

Is this possible, and if so, how do I go about it?

Comment: Each installation of SSRS is an *instance* and has it's own ReportServer database on a SQL Server instance. No such *instance* "points" to another *instance*, so it isn't clear what you want.

Comment: I don't want multiple instances of SSRS on a single SQL instance. I am looking to keep the current SSRS 2014 instance on the prod SQL instance, but then install SSRS 2017 and point it to the prod\Test SQL instance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. What does "points" mean and what is **the** prod\Test SQL instance (these are **two**)? You can install SSRS on another server and connect it to a ReportServer database on a different server, but you will not be able to use one ReportServer database with 2 different SSRS versions.

Comment: Do you mean that you would like to install SSRS 2017 into the test instance of SQL Server? If the test instance is on a compatible version of SQL Server & currently has no SSRS installed in it at all, that /may/ perhaps be possible, but you are likely to have to faff around considerably to ensure that all the relevant processes, and in particular sockets e.g. Report Manager, can run happily alongside your SSRS 2014 installation in a single Windows instance. Personally I'd move the test instance to a different server (good practice anyway really).

Comment: Thanks @MandyShaw, Yes that is what I wanted to do. I will do what you suggested instead